# In XSD, is there a way to allow any element OR a raw string?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm very new to XSD and to schemas in general, but I need to allow the contents of a given element to contain any element or a raw string.

Obviously `xsd:any` can be used to allow any child elements, but only solves half of the issue. Is there a way to achieve the effects of `xsd:any` while also allowing a raw string for the element's contents?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the complex type as `mixed` and it will allow Mixed Content.

If you don't want to declare each element, you can use `<xs:any>` with `processContents="lax"`.

This might be what you are looking for:

```
<xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```